# Screenshot saving error JavaFX

Tags: javafx, screenshot

I am trying to save a screenshot of the current scene using javaFX.

```
saveMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

                // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                fileChooser.setTitle("Save Image");
                File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
                if(file != null)
                {
                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't Save.");

                    }
                }
            }  
        });
```

But my compiler NetBeans IDE 8.1 is giving an error:

```
incompatible types: SnapshotParameters cannot be converted to Callback<SnapshotResult, Void>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

And your compiler is right. A Scene just does not have a method like the one you are trying to call. Just use

```
  WritableImage image = scene.snapshot(null);
```